# Nginx config error when using a Docker Container running the latest version of nginx from dockerhub (nginx:alpine)

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

I have a nginx error and i'm wondering why this is happening, on debian 10 server this config works perfectly but on my alpine nginx docker container it gives this error

```
/etc/nginx # nginx -t
2020/01/17 18:13:06 [emerg] 189#189: unexpected "s" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phpMyAdmin.conf:33
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "s" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phpMyAdmin.conf:33
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This is the config file https://pastebin.com/CwELESRB
This is the line in question that is giving the error

`add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";`

Any help is extremely appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see with your directive is the placement of semi-colon, it should be within the quotes.

> add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';"

There are some examples at the bottom of this [page](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: It still has the same error, but as I said on my debian 10 server that I was using there was no config error, only one on this alpine docker machine.